# Filtering XML based on Xpath condition from different nodes

Tags: xml, xpath, filter

Need to check the existence of XML nodes, using Xpath expression where conditions are from different nodes /level.

I have a XML which has the root node occurrence 0..unbounded. The XML has several child nodes maintained with multiple occurrences. Need to find if there is at least one root node based on the conditions.
This is basically an IDOc XML structure with several child segments with multiple occurrences. As per the picture attached , we have to count only those IDocs , where VKORG =1140 and VTWEG =01 and WERKS =1136 and SPART =00, here SPART will be only once in an IDoc structure but other fields can repeat. The IDoc node can repeat multiple times.

[image: IDocXML]

Comment: Below Xpath expression I created and it worked -
//E1MARAM[contains(SPART, '00') and .//ZOMI036_CHARLIST/IDOC_FOR[text()="DC"] and .//E1MARCM/WERKS[text()="1136"] and .//E1MVKEM[VKORG/text()="1140"] [VTWEG/text()="01"]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below Xpath expression I created and it worked - //E1MARAM[contains(SPART, '00') and .//ZOMI036_CHARLIST/IDOC_FOR[text()="DC"] and .//E1MARCM/WERKS[text()="1136"] and .//E1MVKEM[VKORG/text()="1140"] [VTWEG/text()="01"]]